# How to get the value of selected option

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to get the value of the selected option but i couldn't, any help:

i am pretty new to JavaScript

help is very appreciated.

here is my code

```js
btn = document.getElementById('submitbtn')
btn.addEventListener('click', checkOverallRating);
let overall = document.querySelector('select');
let overallValue = overall.options[overall.selectedIndex].text
function checkOverallRating(e){
  if (overall == 0) {
    alert(overallValue);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
    alert(overallValue);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<select method="POST" name="OverallRating" id="OverallRating" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option value= 0 selected>Select the desired Overall Rating</option>
  <option value="5">Outstanding Performance</option>
  <option value="4">Excceds Target</option>
  <option value="3">Meets Target</option>
  <option value="2">Partially Meets Target</option>
  <option value="1">Needs Improvement</option>
</select>
      
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let answer = document.querySelector('#OverallRating').value;

Comment: Thank u it worked in the console but the condition doesnt work i.e answer === 2

Comment: Thank u worked but had to use the whole document.querySelector('#OverallRating').value to work fine with the condition. Using variable always changes to default value in select options

Comment: If the value of string in the option is 2 and you need to compare it to the type of 2, it will always result in false but you gotta covert it into a integer using `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that below code snippets is outside `checkOverallRating()`,**it will executed once your page is loaded and keeps the same no matter which option you select**

```
    let overall = document.querySelector('select');
    let overallValue = overall.options[overall.selectedIndex].text
```

In order to make it works as your expected,you need to put them inside `checkOverallRating()`

```html
<form>
<select method="POST" name="OverallRating" id="OverallRating" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
        <option value= 0 selected>Select the desired Overall Rating</option>
        <option value="5">Outstanding Performance</option>
        <option value="4">Excceds Target</option>
        <option value="3">Meets Target</option>
        <option value="2">Partially Meets Target</option>
        <option value="1">Needs Improvement</option>
      </select>
      
      <button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>

</form>

<script>
    btn = document.getElementById('submitbtn')
    btn.addEventListener('click', checkOverallRating);
    function checkOverallRating(e){
        let overall = document.querySelector('select');
        let overallValue = overall.options[overall.selectedIndex].text
        if (overall == 0) {
            alert(overallValue);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            alert(overallValue);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the selected value immediately upon loading the page, before the user has selected anything.

Don't try to read the selected value until after the user has selected something.  Such as in your button click handler:

```js
btn = document.getElementById('submitbtn')
btn.addEventListener('click', checkOverallRating);
function checkOverallRating(e){
  // move these two lines into the function...
  let overall = document.querySelector('select');
  let overallValue = overall.options[overall.selectedIndex].text

  if (overall == 0) {
    alert(overallValue);
    e.preventDefault();
  } else {
    alert(overallValue);
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<select method="POST" name="OverallRating" id="OverallRating" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option value= 0 selected>Select the desired Overall Rating</option>
  <option value="5">Outstanding Performance</option>
  <option value="4">Excceds Target</option>
  <option value="3">Meets Target</option>
  <option value="2">Partially Meets Target</option>
  <option value="1">Needs Improvement</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
```

As an aside... Your `if` statement makes no sense because an HTML element object will never equal `0`.  But the good news is that the `if` statement is also entirely unnecessary because you're doing the same thing in both cases.  So just remove it:

```js
btn = document.getElementById('submitbtn')
btn.addEventListener('click', checkOverallRating);
function checkOverallRating(e){
  // move these two lines into the function...
  let overall = document.querySelector('select');
  let overallValue = overall.options[overall.selectedIndex].text

  alert(overallValue);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<select method="POST" name="OverallRating" id="OverallRating" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option value= 0 selected>Select the desired Overall Rating</option>
  <option value="5">Outstanding Performance</option>
  <option value="4">Excceds Target</option>
  <option value="3">Meets Target</option>
  <option value="2">Partially Meets Target</option>
  <option value="1">Needs Improvement</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fetch the id of the select input and it will return the value of the selected option

```
document.getElementById(OverallRating).value;
```